# Cross join and insert values into a table in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL table like the following:

```
item    | subitem    |   stage    |   id     | 
-----------------------------------------------
i1      | s1         |  picked    |    1     |
i1      | s2         |  shipped   |    1     |
i2      | s4         |  picked    |    2     |
i3      | s10        | shipped    |    2     |
i3      | s11        | eligible   |    0     |
i4      | s2         |not eligible|    0     |
i1      | s1         |  picked    |    3     |
i1      | s2         |  picked    |    3     |
```

I want the output to be like the following:

```
item1|subitem1|item2|subitem2|pair_volume|item1pick|item1ship|item2pick|item2ship|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
i1   |   s1   |  i1 | s2     | 2         |  2      | 0       | 2       | 1       |
i1   | s1     | i2  | s4     | 1         |1        | 0       | 1       | 1       |  

....
.....
....
```

Essentially, what I want to do here is the following:

I want to first make a cross-join of `item, subitem` with itself, so I have all possible combinations of `item1`, `subitem1` and `item2`, `subitem2`.

Here's how the stages are defined. If a stage is eligible, then it is just eligible, whereas if a stage is picked, then it means that item is both eligible and picked. If a stage is shipped, then it means that item is eligible, picked and shipped. Only the last stage is mentioned.

Now, for every `item1, subitem1 - item2, subitem2` pair, I want to calculate the count of `id` sessions where this pair occurs and has stage in `(eligible, shipped, picked)` and populate the value in `pair_volume`. For eg, `(i1,s1)-(i1,s2)` pair occurs twice (once in `id` 1 and once in `id` 3) and in both these `id` sessions, both the items in the pair were `eligible` (which is implied from `picked` and `shipped`) stages. Out of the 2 times that this eligible pair occurred, how many times is item1 picked, item2 picked, item1 shipped and item2 shipped? This is what I am trying to solve.

I can do fine until cross join. But I don't know how to insert values into the cross joined table. Any help is much appreciated!

Here's what I have so far:

```
select combination.item1, combination.subitem1, combination.item2, 
combination.subitem2,
    (
    select tmp.item1, tmp.subitem1, tmp.item2, tmp.subitem2,
    case when ((tmp.item1 = tmp.item2) and 
    (tmp.subitem1 = tmp.subitem2)) then 'TRUE' else 
    'FALSE' end as indicator from
        (
        select distinct item as item1, subitem as subitem2
        from old
        cross join
        select distinct item as item2, subitem as subitem2 
        from old
        ) tmp
    ) combination
where combination.indicator = 'FALSE'
```

The query up until cross join works fine . But I don't know how to proceed further to compute the extra columns. Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If you know how to do the cross join, just put that after `INSERT INTO tablename` to insert the results into the table.

Comment: Please share your query

Comment: @Barmar: I have pasted my query... `insert into` didn't work for me

Comment: @Jervs: Hi, I have shared my query for cross join..Hope you can help me out!